# add_action and Ajax

Tags: ajax, actions

I'm developing a plugin and I've started from [WPPB](http://wppb.io/) and Wordpress 4.3.1. I've named it dogmaweb. I need to submit a form to the plugin via Ajax. The form is created by the plugin itself. In my class-dogmaweb.php I'm trying to add the action that processes the form data server side, and here is what I've come up with, until now:

```
public function enqueue_scripts()
{
  $script_handle = 'userprofilesumbit';
  add_action( 'wp_ajax_'.$script_handle, array($this, 'userprofileform_process') );
  add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_'.$script_handle, array($this, 'userprofileform_process') );
  wp_register_script( $script_handle, plugins_url() . '/public/js/dogmaweb-public.js' );
  $userprofilesumbit_data = array('ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ), 'form_action' => $script_handle, 'form_id' => '#'.Dogmaweb::$userprofileform_id);
  wp_localize_script($script_handle, 'submit_params', $userprofilesumbit_data);
  wp_enqueue_script($script_handle);
}
```

The symptom of the problem is that admin-ajax.php is not calling my function and it is returning 0. I've stepped through the wordpress code to understand why (I'm using Netbeans and xdebug). The problem is that [these lines of code in plugin.php](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/4.3-branch/wp-includes/plugin.php#L475-L479) do not find the `$tag` in the `$wp_filter` array. The `$tag` variable at that point contains `"wp_ajax_userprofilesumbit"`, which is exactly what I specified for the `$hook` argument to the add_action function (I've used the same `$script_handle` variable as you can see in my code).
I've also stepped through the `add_action` code and I'm sure the global `$wp_filter` array does contain `"wp_ajax_userprofilesumbit"` key when `add_action` returns after I call it. However I'm also sure that it does not contain that key anymore when plugin.php executes (called by admin-ajax.php).

Why is my filter being removed from `$wp_filter`? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I skimmed through the plugin's code and you could try to use the `define_public_hooks()` method of the `Plugin_Name`  class to register your ajax action callbacks of the `Plugin_Name_Public` class:

```
/**
 * Register all of the hooks related to the public-facing functionality
 * of the plugin.
 *
 * @since    1.0.0
 * @access   private
 */
private function define_public_hooks() {

    $plugin_public = new Plugin_Name_Public( $this->get_plugin_name(), $this->get_version() );

    $this->loader->add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', $plugin_public, 'enqueue_styles' );
    $this->loader->add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', $plugin_public, 'enqueue_scripts' );

    // Add your ajax actions here instead 
    $script_handle = 'userprofilesumbit';   
    $this->loader->add_action(  'wp_ajax_' . $script_handle, $plugin_public, 'userprofileform_process' );
    $this->loader->add_action(  'wp_ajax_nopriv_' . $script_handle, $plugin_public, 'userprofileform_process' );

}
```

Answer (score 3):

What is happening there is that you need to move:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_'.$script_handle, array($this, 'userprofileform_process') );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_'.$script_handle, array($this, 'userprofileform_process') );
```

Out of the `enqueue_scripts` function, because the way it is setup these actions are not been hooked, because this function will only execute on front-end actions.

Comment: Both your answer and @birgire one are correct and both helped me understand. Yours came first, but his answer is more complete and suggests where to put the add_action calls. I upvoted yours but I'm accepting his answer because of that. Thanks a lot to both of you anyway.

Comment: Awesome! I'm really glad I was able to help you.